# How do I use the Vim plugin VCSCommand to diff/commit/etc on a directory? (or... What is a VIm "directory buffer"?)

Tags: vim, vcscommand

(I am a VIM-n00b)

According to the VCSCommand docs, the commands will operate on a directory if you are currently in a "directory buffer".  I can't seem to find any other references to opening a "directory buffer" though.

What am I (probably very stupidly) missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is buffer with `filetype=netrw`: if you open a directory in vim (for example, try `vim .`), it will use `netrw` plugin which is distributed with the official package.

Comment: Ah... you put me on the right path!  First, you can open a directory buffer within the session using ":e ."  Unfortunately (for those using it), if you are using NERDTree, the vcscommand actions won't work.  I happily disabled NERDTree (since I'm using Command-T), and now everything is perfect.  Thanks!