# How to put current directory in vim command line

Tags: vim

I'd like to call the VCSStatus function passing the current working directory (whatever `:pwd` returns) to it. It has to be the full path, and no special characters such as "." are accepted.

Comment: IIRC I believe that only works with a special modification to NERDtree. I'll look around for the right information...

Comment: Oh [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072472/how-do-i-use-the-vim-plugin-vcscommand-to-diff-commit-etc-on-a-directory-or) It's not a modification to NERDtree, but rather that you can't have NERDtree active since it looks for netrw.  The modification I was misremembering was to bind a keystroke to disable NERDTree temporarily while using VCSCommand.

Comment: I don't have NERDtree, so that shouldn't be a problem here. All I want is to expand the current directory when executing a command. Also, I'm on windows.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it is a Windows issue.  I just tested `:VCSStatus .` (for a svn project) and I got the correct output for the current working dir.

Comment: What version of VCSCommand do you have?

Comment: The latest from vim.org/scripts. The thing is, I want to perform operations on entire directories, and not just on the current active buffer... like "commit this_folder" or "status that_folder".

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It works as long as your don't open a file in a subdirectory.

Comment: So, is there nothing like "%" but for the current working directory?

Comment: `:VCSCommit ./subdir` works for me on Linux too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:execute 'VCSStatus' getcwd()
```

should do the trick. Should you wish to use the current file's directory instead, it'd be:

```
:execute 'VCSStatus' expand('%:p:h')
```

(`%` refers to the current file, `:p` modifies to a full absolute path, and `:h` cuts off the filename; cp. `:help filename-modifiers`)

Comment: The directory of the current file is not the same as the current directory.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have `'autochdir'` set, so it doesn't make a difference for me :-) The fix is even easier; I've added it to my answer.